# How to add template page dynamically with dynamic values in it in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Actually I'm very new to angularJS so I'm asking some basic questions which may seem silly to you geeks. I am habituate of jQuery a bit much thats why some confusion is there as docs are also very limited.

```
    <!Doctype>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Example - example-example12-production</title>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="docsTemplateUrlDirective">
      <div ng-controller="Controller as c">
      <button ng-click="c.showdiv()">show</button >
      <div id="d"></div>
    </div>
<script>

angular.module('docsTemplateUrlDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
this.showdiv=function(){

    //do the ajax call and get the value from server
    //pick the required template
    //render the returned value on picked template

}
}]);
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want whenever I clicked and call showdiv() it should call ajax,get the value and render it in a template(say template.html) in div(id=d) section

Update: 1.say we have two button.if button1 is clicked then it will pick template1.html anf for button2 its template2.html.

2.ajax returns as {"Name":"AnyName","Age":"25"} like that
in template1.html has binding as

```
<div>
{{Name}},{{Age}}
</div>
```

for button2 different value with different template style.

Comment: So both the template and the content in it have to be dynamic? or will the template always be template.html?

Comment: Also, you are missing a closing square bracket in your controller definition

Comment: "Pick the required template", you mean that the server is sending you an id or something back? What does the server return? Btw check out $http for ajax calls. And you probably want to change "this" into "$scope".

Comment: @jeffcarey,Tom: I updated can you please give hint/solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your div "d" to say:

```
<div id="d" ng-include="chosenTemplate"></div>
```

Update buttons:

```
<button ng-click="c.showdiv('template1.html')">show 1</button >
<button ng-click="c.showdiv('template2.html')">show 2</button >
```

Then add something like the following:

```
this.showdiv = function(theTemplate) {

    $scope.chosenTemplate = theTemplate;

    // do AJAX call using $http.get
    $scope.Name = "John Smith";
    $scope.Age = 25;
}
```

Also note:

As mentioned above you can add the showdiv function to the scope so you won't have to prefix it with "c." in your html.

As I mentioned above you are missing a closing square bracket ] at the end of your controller definition.

Comment: Thanks tried and worked well. I guess/hope this might a good way to get the serverside value and render it in a template.